# How to add the mean line to grouped density plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, density-plot

I am trying to draw a grouped density plot and add the mean line of each plot; here is the code

```
data <- data.frame(
 Accuracy=abs(rnorm(140)),
Species=c(rep("A.All",20),rep("B. double",60),rep("C.single",60),
          rep("D.All",20),rep("E.double",60),rep("F.single",60)),

Modality=c(rep("All,w0",10),rep("double1,w0",10),rep("double2,w0",10),rep("double3,w0",10),
          rep("single1,w0",10),rep("single2,w0",10),rep("single3,w0",10),
          rep("All,w2",10),rep("double1,w2",10),rep("double2,w2",10),rep("double3,w2",10),
          rep("single1,w2",10),rep("single2,w2",10),rep("single3,w2",10))
)


p<-ggplot(data, aes(x=Accuracy, fill=Modality)) +
 geom_density(alpha=0.4)+
 facet_wrap(. ~ Species) +
 xlab("Accuracy") + ylab("Density")

library(plyr)
mu <- ddply(data, "Modality", summarise, grp.mean=mean(Accuracy))
head(mu)


# Add mean lines
a<-p+geom_vline(data=mu, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color=Modality),
                linetype="dashed")+ xlab("Accuracy") + ylab("Density")
```

However, based on the output figure as
[image]

The mean lines are absolutely incorrect, e.g. for the first picture on the top left, there should be two lines for two density plots, but a couple of lines are created and being repeated for all the figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may specify both `Species` and `Modality`

## `plyr`

```
dummy <- ddply(data, c("Species","Modality"), summarise, grp.mean=mean(Accuracy))

ggplot(data, aes(x=Accuracy, fill=Modality)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.4)+
  facet_wrap(. ~ Species) +
  xlab("Accuracy") + ylab("Density") +
  geom_vline(data = dummy, aes(xintercept = grp.mean, color = Modality))
```

## `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)



dummy <- data %>%
  group_by(Species, Modality) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(Accuracy))

ggplot(data, aes(x=Accuracy, fill=Modality)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.4)+
  facet_wrap(. ~ Species) +
  xlab("Accuracy") + ylab("Density") +
  geom_vline(data = dummy, aes(xintercept = mean, color = Modality))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I get this error from your code "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Modality' not found".

Comment: @Katie It does work for me. Does `Modality` column is inside of `data`? Where did that error occurs?

Comment: I ran the same code you ran, but I am not sure why it is giving me this error.

Comment: @Katie May you try with `data` you specify above in your question? And, where does that error occurs?

Comment: @Katie Have a nice day :D.

Comment: You helped me a lot! I was really exhausted.